# How I add function in query in PHP

Tags: php, function, encryption, fetch

I created an encryption and decryption function in PHP which insert encrypted data in the database. But I am getting an error in fetching data when I want decryption with this is function `decrypt_data()`

**Real Query**

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT `useranme` FROM `logindb` WHERE username = '$username'");
```

**I made**

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT `useranme` FROM `logindb` WHERE username= decrypt_data('$username')");
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) { ... }
//--But it is not works--//
// -- LocalHost error : Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object -- //
```

How I made it correct Please help me in creating a code correct as I want

Comment: Do not forget to include your function as well.

Answer (score -1):

While you can put a variable name inside of a double quoted string, you can't place a function inside of a string, and expect it to execute.

Instead, what you'll want to do is

```
$encrypted_username = encrypt_data($username);
$sql = $con->query("SELECT `username` FROM `logindb` WHERE username='$encrypted_username'");
```

or

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT `username` FROM `logindb` WHERE username='" . encrypt_data($username) . "'");
```

Since you're storing the username encrypted in the DB, you're going to want to encrypt the $username before running your query instead of decrypting it, so that it will match something that is in the DB. In fact, you'll probably never need to run your decrypt_data function at all.

Note: Any hacker who gains access to your server will also have access to all of the details of your encryption algorithm, so it might be a sleight annoyance to the hacker, but this doesn't offer a whole lot of benefit in terms of security. Also, I hope that for the password field you're hashing your passwords instead of using this encryption function.

Comment: So what is the methode so we can protect our data end to end?

Comment: This article seems to do a good job explaining the difference between hashing and encryption https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security.  Basically hashing is a one way encryption function that can encrypt data but cannot decrypt it. It's ok for it to be one way because you can take the password, hash it, and check if the hash matches what is in the DB. There is no need to ever decrypt anything.

Comment: I've updated the second one to surround the username in quotes which is needed if there is any whitespace in the encrypted usernames. Does it work now?

Comment: I just realized that you had **username** spelled wrong in your question. I've updated both examples to use the correct spelling. Make sure you have that fixed in your code too.